# Show that if $f(z)=\frac{\operatorname{Log}z}{z-1}$ when $z\neq 1$ and $f(1)=1$, then $f$ is analytic throughout the domain.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

$\operatorname{Log}z=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(z-1)^n \; (|z-1|\lt 1).$

Use this fact to show that if

$$f(z)=\frac{\operatorname{Log}z}{z-1} \; \text{when} z\neq 1$$

and $f(1)=1$, then $f$ is analytic throughout the domain

$$0\lt |z| \lt \infty, -\pi \lt \operatorname{Arg}z\lt \pi.$$

I'm trying to use the theorem that if a function has a power series representation, then it is analytic throughout the interior of its circle of convergence, and show that the series at $1$ is equal to $1$. However, since the domain of the series $\operatorname{Log}z$ and the one given in the end are different, I don't know how to find such representation.

I would greatly appreciate some help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ be the larger domain. Certainly $f$ is analytic in $U\setminus \{1\}.$ But $f$ is also analytic in $D(1,1).$ Why? Because it equals a power series centered at $1$ there. Thus for any point in $U,$ $f'(z)$ exists. Hence $f$ is analytic in $U.$